# Post login with file_get_contents - not curl

Tags: php, file-get-contents

One site requires login for three variables: username, password and token. This data is sent via POST.

token is also sent through a section.

I have all three variables, and I want to log in via file_get_contents.

How can that data be sent and the authentication is successful?

```
    function file_post_contents()
{

    $url = 'http://site.com/auth.php?' . session_name() . '=' . session_id();

    $login = 'jhon';
    $senha = 'doe';

    $token = '123456';  
    $_SESSION["token"] = $token;

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'login' => $login,
            'senha' => $senha,
            'token' => $token, 
                            $_SESSION["token"] => $token
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    if($login && $senha)
    {
        $opts['http']['header'] = ("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$login:$senha"));
    }

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

---

Modified code. It does not work.

```
    function file_post_contents()
{

    $url = 'http://site.com/auth.php?' . session_name() . '=' . session_id();

    $login = 'jhon';
    $senha = 'doe';

    $token = '123456';  
    $_SESSION["token"] = $token;

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'login' => $login,
            'senha' => $senha,
            'token' => $token
            //, $_SESSION["token"] => $token
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             . "\r\n" . "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$login:$senha"). "\r\n",
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );


    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
```

Comment: what does this returns to you? it looks correct ...

Comment: Yes, it looks correct, but returns the error message that it can not connect.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It's a personalized message. The message is this: "Incorrect data. Verify and try again"

Comment: so the data does gets sent but something is invalid with your data. You have to figure out what is the incorrect data.

Comment: Did you mean `$_SESSION["token"]` do be a field NAME, not field VALUE? That's weird..? You're now sending `['123456' => '123456']` with...

Comment: I added this line trying to send the session, and it did not work. Even after correcting the error, does not work. I'll remove the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers might be set wrong, try adding `\r\n` like so

```
$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
```

and later down the code

`$opts['http']['header'] = $opts['http']['header'] . "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$login:$senha") . "\r\n";`

Comment: It seems that the problem is in data transmission session.

Before using file_get_content without creating the session, the same error was displayed.

So I created the session and managed to perform authentication.

Now, using file_get_content comes the error message that informed. So it seems that the problem is to send session data when using file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding `$opts['http']['header']` with the Basic auth. You're not adding it to the Content-type, you're replacing Content-type with it.